# Detecting whether an anchor doesn't exist in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe that is loading content dynamically from a **different URL**. 
The content is a certain anchor inside a relatively long webpage.
So my question is - is there any option to detect whether an anchor exists within a webpage upon loading it to the iframe (without using server-side .. )?

for example, If something like that is possible somehow , it will serve the purpose:

```
$('iframe').load({success: function(){...}, failure: function(){..})
$('iframe').attr('src','http://url.com/index.html#anchor-01');
```

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot ACCESS the Iframe contents with JavaScript, because of Cross-Domain policy!

Comment: I know, I'm not interested in accessing the content, just knowing whether the complete URL (including the anchor inside the page) exists.. Is it the same thing as accessing the content itself?

Comment: sure it is.. whether you want to see something in the contents, alter something, remove something - it is a direct accessing into the iframe contents!

Comment: OK , It appears there's no way out of this... Thanks guys.

Comment: @Deadlock  `size()` is deprecated...use `length` instead

Comment: one option is use Yahoo YQL to scrape the page , return the `<a>` tags in jsonp and check results for tag you are looking for. Can be done with `$.getJSON` and no server code

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for pointing out... Was not aware of that... Really appreciate it..